# My phone can't start after backup failed

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, unbricking

I tried backing up my Galaxy S4 using this method:
http://galaxys4root.com/galaxy-s4-tutorials/how-to-backuprestore-rom-on-galaxy-s4-with-root-cwm-recovery/

1. 1st backup failed but I could still boot the phone
   When backing up, it failed halfway, it failed backing up /data/.
   I rebooted my phone and found that my keyboard doesn't remember my custom words anymore.
2. 2nd backup failed and I can't start the phone anymore
   I rebooted into the recovery and tried backing it up again the second time.
   It failed halfway, it failed backing up /system/.
   Then I tried the backup again (without rebooting) and it failed immediately saying no space on the SD card (I am not sure if it's true)

So I rebooted the phone and it is showing the boot animation forever (I waited over 30 mins).

I tried restoring /system/ from the first backup but it didn't help.

I don't even know where the problem is, how can a backup break your phone??
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've just added the `boot-loop` tag, please check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) for first aid. Btw: restoring `/system` was pretty unnecessary here: as that's read-only, it wasn't changed in between. You should check your available free space on the SDCard (where your backups go to) and make sure you have about twice the space your other partitions consume ("twice" is kinda "safety margin"), as the Nandroid backup copies their images here.

Comment: Thanks Izzy, but how can I do that without booting into Android?

Comment: Did you follow the link I posted with my previous comment? All explained there. If you've tried that, please [edit] your question and include that information. It's hard to give advice when you never tell what advice you've followed already :) *EDIT:* Just saw your answer now, so you have been able to resolve the issue with that information. Glad to read, and thanks for answering yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did a Wipe/Factory reset. I lost all apps and data, but at least I can use my phone again.

And yes, that was because I ran out of space in the internal SD card.